# facing issues with wrapper in wrapper class

Tags: wrapper-class

I am trying to implement something like to display open carts and this repctive cart line items

Something like

```
Cart1 details
  Cartlineitem1 details
  Cartlineitemdetails2

Cart2 details
 Cartlineitem3details
 Cartlineitem4details
```

I have used a wrapper in wrapper class.

I am able to show only one line item details under each cart detail  not the list, not sure where I am creating an issue.

Code used is as below

```
public  class OpenCartController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<CartWrapper> cartWrapper1 {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public static List<CartWrapper> DisplayOpenRecords(String CartStatus){

   Quote_Cart__c cartForFilter  = new Quote_Cart__c();
   boolean showStoper =true ;
   boolean showandHideButton = true;
   boolean showExising = false ; 



   system.debug('The user id info: '+UserInfo.getUserId());
   String selectedCartStatus = '';

       List<Quote_Cart__c> cartforUsers = new List<Quote_Cart__c>();
        Set<ID> Cartids = new Set<ID>();

    if(CartStatus=='Open'){
       List<Quote_Cart__c> open  = [SELECT recordType__C,Id, Price_Exception__c ,lastmodifieddate,Requested_Delivery_Date__c,Account__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Name__c,Cart_Approval_Status__c,Account__r.Name , 
                 GEW_Account_DUNS__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Id__c,Quote_Number__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Type__c, GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c,Ship_To_SAP__c,Sales_Org__c,RecordType.Name, Name,createddate,
                 GEW_SAP_Contract__c  
                FROM Quote_Cart__c
                WHERE OwnerId=:UserInfo.getUserId()  
                AND GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c=:CartStatus 
                ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
                LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(System.Label.Reorder_ShoppingCart_Page_QuoteCart_Limit)] ; // Modified on "IFO CFO Parts Ordering UAT Log (IT Fixes)"
       cartforUsers.addAll(open);   
        }
    else
    {List<Quote_Cart__c> open  = [SELECT recordType__C,Id, Price_Exception__c ,lastmodifieddate,Requested_Delivery_Date__c,Account__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Name__c,Cart_Approval_Status__c,Account__r.Name , 
                 GEW_Account_DUNS__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Id__c,Quote_Number__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Type__c, GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c,Ship_To_SAP__c,Sales_Org__c,RecordType.Name, Name,createddate,
                 GEW_SAP_Contract__c  
                FROM Quote_Cart__c
                WHERE OwnerId=:UserInfo.getUserId()  
                AND GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c!='Open' 
                ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
                LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(System.Label.Reorder_ShoppingCart_Page_QuoteCart_Limit)] ; 
       cartforUsers.addAll(open);  }
    if (cartforUsers.size()>0){
        for(Quote_Cart__c carts: cartforUsers){
            Cartids.add(carts.Id);

        }

    }

     List<Quote_Line_Item__C> CartLine = [SELECT Id, Name, Quote_Cart__c,Material_Id__c, Quantity__c,GEW_Display_Product__c FROM Quote_Line_Item__c where Quote_Cart__c IN: Cartids];
    system.debug('the list of returned records' +cartforUsers+'\n size:'+cartforUsers.size());

    Boolean isSelected = false ;
    cartWrapper1 = new List<CartWrapper>() ;
    system.debug('after initialization '+cartWrapper1);
    for(Quote_Cart__c qc: cartforUsers){

       CartWrapper cw = new CartWrapper(qc.Id ,
                                        qc.GEW_CC_Cart_Name__c,
                                        qc.Account__r.Name, 
                                        qc.GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c,
                                        qc.Sales_Org__c , 
                                        qc.GEW_CC_Cart_Type__c,
                                        qc.GEW_Account_DUNS__c,
                                        qc.Ship_To_SAP__c ,
                                        qc.GEW_SAP_Contract__c ,
                                        qc.RecordType.Name,
                                        qc.RecordType__c,
                                        qc.Account__r.Id,
                                        qc.Requested_Delivery_Date__c,
                                        Date.ValueOf(qc.CreatedDate),
                                        //Date.ValueOf(qc.lastmodifieddate),
                                        Date.ValueOf(qc.lastmodifieddate),
                                        //lastmodified,
                                        qc.Price_Exception__c,
                                        qc.Name);
        for(Quote_Line_Item__C QL:CartLine){
            if(QL.Quote_Cart__c==qc.Id){
              cw.lineItems=new List<CartLineWrapper>()  ;
               cw.lineItems.add(new CartLineWrapper(QL)); 
            }
        }
        cartWrapper1.add(cw);
                }

     return cartWrapper1;
}     

/**
* Utility method.
* @param  - Date time 
* @Return - String  
*/     


 @AuraEnabled  
 public  static String formatDate(DateTime lastmodified)
 {
     return lastmodified.format('MMM dd, YYYY - HH:MM:SS');
 }

@AuraEnabled
public static List<CartWrapper>  deleteRecord(ID id, String CartStatus){
                delete [Select id from Quote_Cart__c where id=:id ];
 Set<ID> Cartids = new Set<ID>();   
List<Quote_Cart__c> cartforUsers = new List<Quote_Cart__c>();


       List<Quote_Cart__c> open  = [SELECT recordType__C,Id, Price_Exception__c ,lastmodifieddate,Requested_Delivery_Date__c,Account__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Name__c,Cart_Approval_Status__c,Account__r.Name , 
                 GEW_Account_DUNS__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Id__c,Quote_Number__c,GEW_CC_Cart_Type__c, GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c,Ship_To_SAP__c,Sales_Org__c,RecordType.Name, Name,createddate,
                 GEW_SAP_Contract__c  
                FROM Quote_Cart__c
                WHERE OwnerId=:UserInfo.getUserId()  
                AND GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c=:CartStatus 
                ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
                LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(System.Label.Reorder_ShoppingCart_Page_QuoteCart_Limit)] ; // Modified on "IFO CFO Parts Ordering UAT Log (IT Fixes)"
       cartforUsers.addAll(open);   
     List<Quote_Line_Item__C> CartLine = [SELECT Id, Name, Quote_Cart__c,Material_Id__c,GEW_Display_Product__c, Quantity__c FROM Quote_Line_Item__c where Quote_Cart__c IN: Cartids];




    system.debug('the list of returned records' +cartforUsers+'\n size:'+cartforUsers.size());

    Boolean isSelected = false ;
    cartWrapper1 = new List<CartWrapper>() ;
    system.debug('after initialization '+cartWrapper1);
    for(Quote_Cart__c qc: cartforUsers){
        for(Quote_Line_Item__C QL:CartLine){
            if(qc.id==QL.Quote_Cart__c){
       CartWrapper cw = new CartWrapper(qc.Id ,
                                        qc.GEW_CC_Cart_Name__c,
                                        qc.Account__r.Name, 
                                        qc.GEW_CC_Cart_Status__c,
                                        qc.Sales_Org__c , 
                                        qc.GEW_CC_Cart_Type__c,
                                        qc.GEW_Account_DUNS__c,
                                        qc.Ship_To_SAP__c ,
                                        qc.GEW_SAP_Contract__c ,
                                        qc.RecordType.Name,
                                        qc.RecordType__c,
                                        qc.Account__r.Id,
                                        qc.Requested_Delivery_Date__c,
                                        Date.ValueOf(qc.CreatedDate),
                                        //Date.ValueOf(qc.lastmodifieddate),
                                        Date.ValueOf(qc.lastmodifieddate),
                                        //lastmodified,
                                        qc.Price_Exception__c,
                                        qc.Name
                                        );
        cartWrapper1.add(cw);
                }
        }
        } 
     return cartWrapper1;

}






public class CartWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public boolean disable {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String recId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String cartName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String account{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String cartStatus{get ;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String salesOrg {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String typeOf{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String DUNS {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String ShipTo {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String Contract {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String ERPContract {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String RecordTypeName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String recType {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public Date reuestedDate{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String accountId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String PEStatus {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public Date createDate {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    //public Date modifiedDate {get; set;}
    public Date modifiedDate {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String modifiedDate2 {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String peNumber {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String quoteCartNumber {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public Id peId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled  
    public String lastmodified{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled

  public List<CartLineWrapper> lineItems {get; set;}
 public CartWrapper(String recId,
                    String cartName,
                    String account, 
                    String cartStatus,
                    String salesOrg , 
                    String typeOf,
                    String DUNS, 
                    String ShipTo,
                    String ERPContract,
                    String RecordTypeName,
                    String recType,
                    String accountId,
                    Date reuestedDate,
                    Date createDate,
                    Date modifiedDate ,
                    //String lastmodified,
                    Id peNumber,
                    String quoteCartNumber                       ){
                             selected = false;
                             disable = false;
                             this.recId  = recId  ;
                             this.cartName  = cartName  ;
                             this.account= account;
                             this.cartStatus= cartStatus;
                             this.salesOrg = salesOrg ;
                             this.typeOf  = typeOf;
                             this.DUNS = DUNS;
                             this.ERPContract = ERPContract ; 
                             this.ShipTo =ShipTo;
                             this.RecordTypeName = RecordTypeName ; 
                             this.reuestedDate  = reuestedDate  ;
                             this.recType = rectype;
                             this.accountId = accountid;
                             this.createDate  = createDate  ;
                             this.modifiedDate  = modifiedDate  ;
                             this.lastmodified = lastmodified;
                             this.quoteCartNumber = quoteCartNumber;
                             this.peID = peNumber;
                            //  this.QuoteCartLine=ql;
                             //system.debug('UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID() -- '+UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID());
                             //this.modifiedDate2 = modifiedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID());
                             //this.modifiedDate2 = modifiedDate.formatLong();                                 
                             if (PENumber !=null)
                             {
                                 system.debug(penumber);
                                 Price_Exeception__c pe = [select final_Approval__c, RequestId__c from price_exeception__c where id =:penumber];
                                 PEStatus = pe.final_Approval__c;
                                 this.peNumber = pe.RequestId__c;
                                 //if (PEStatus == 'Recalled' || PEStatus == 'NO')
                                 if (PEStatus == 'NO')
                                     PEStatus = '';
                             }
    }


  }
 public  class CartLineWrapper{
      @AuraEnabled
public Quote_Line_Item__C CartLine {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
public string material {
    get
    {
        return this.CartLine.Material_Id__c;

    }
}
         @AuraEnabled
public string MatDescription {
    get
    {
        return this.CartLine.GEW_Display_Product__c;

    }
}
           @AuraEnabled
public Decimal MatQuantity {
    get
    {
        return this.CartLine.Quantity__c;

    }
}
     public CartLineWrapper(Quote_Line_Item__C CartLine){
         this.CartLine=CartLine;
     }

 }
}
```

Comment: The code you included has no bearing on your own problem. Would you please edit your question to remove the boilerplate code and add your actual code, limiting to the specific areas that are involved in your problem?

Comment: I have edited the description and now the code represents the issue which i have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way too much code for a simple problem. One of the key approaches to debugging is isolating a *minimal example* - just the code that is *relevant* to your problem and that can be used to evaluate what the issue might be. Copying and pasting a whole class, which includes lots of code that is not connected to the problem, makes debugging much more challenging, for both you and others.

That said....

Here's your proximate problem.

```
        if(QL.Quote_Cart__c==qc.Id){
          cw.lineItems=new List<CartLineWrapper>()  ;
           cw.lineItems.add(new CartLineWrapper(QL)); 
        }
```

Every time you find a Line Item associated to a particular Cart, you re-initialize its `cw.lineItems` property with a new, empty, `List<CartLineWrapper>` and then add that one item to the empty list. As a result, you're only ever going to see one child record, because you're not accumulating results - just overwriting each time.

The ultimate problem, though, is that you're querying for child objects separately from their parents and then iterating to find matches. This is extremely inefficient. Instead, you should refactor your code to use a [parent-child query](https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-relationship-queries) when you originally query for `Quote_Cart__c`. Then, as you create `CartLineWrappers`, you simply iterate over the child relationship property:

```
cw.lineItems = new List<CartLineWrapper>();
for (Quote_Line_Item__C cartLine : QL.Quote_Line_Items__r) {
    cw.lineItems.add(new CartLineWrapper(cartLine));
}
```

Make sure to use the correct [relationship name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) in your query and property reference.

Comment: Thanks David, it did help. I apologize for verbose code, I will try my best to be more specific. I used parent child query and leveraged the same.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: Glad that worked for you!